Speed up the evaluation process
I am writing a code to simulate some spins. Following is the main part of the code:
Ut[β_, γ_] := Dot[U2[β, γ], U3, U4[β, γ], U3, U2[β, γ]];
ρ7[β_, γ_] := Dot[Ut[β, γ], ρ2[β, γ], Ut[β, γ]\[ConjugateTranspose]];
CS3[t_, β_, γ_] = Integrate[ωCSt, t];
ΔCS[β_, γ_] = Re@CS3[time, β, γ] - First@Re@CS3[time, β, γ];
integral4[β_, γ_] := TensorProduct[ΔCS[β, γ], (I2z)];
U7[β_, γ_] := MatrixExp[-I*#] & /@ integral4[β, γ]; 
ρ8[β_, γ_] :=  Dot[#, ρ7[β, γ], #\[ConjugateTranspose]] & /@ U7[β, γ];
FreeEvolve2[β_, γ_] := Tr[(I2x + I I2y)\[ConjugateTranspose].#] & /@ ρ8[β, γ];

The used parameters are as follows:
ωr = 2 π 10;
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 3, 0.004}];
integral1[x_, y_] := {{-0.565685 Cos[0.00628319 + y] Sin[2 x] + 
    Sin[x] (-1.13137 Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
       Sin[x] (0.2 Sin[2. y] - 0.2 Sin[2. (11.0019 + y)])), 2.75046, 
   2.75046, 0.}, {2.75046, 
   0.565685 Cos[0.00628319 + y] Sin[2 x] + 
    Sin[x] (1.13137 Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
       Sin[x] (-0.2 Sin[2. y] + 0.2 Sin[2. (11.0019 + y)])), 0., 
   2.75046}, {2.75046, 0., 
   0.565685 Cos[0.00628319 + y] Sin[2 x] + 
    Sin[x] (1.13137 Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
       Sin[x] (-0.2 Sin[2. y] + 0.2 Sin[2. (11.0019 + y)])), 
   2.75046}, {0., 2.75046, 
   2.75046, -0.565685 Cos[0.00628319 + y] Sin[2 x] + 
    Sin[x] (-1.13137 Cos[x] Sin[y] + 
       Sin[x] (0.2 Sin[2. y] - 0.2 Sin[2. (11.0019 + y)]))}}
integral2[x_, y_] := {{-(3/5) (Sqrt[2] Cos[y] Sin[2 x] - Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[y] +
       Sin[x]^2 Sin[2 y]), 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, -(2/5) (Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] (Cos[y] - Sin[y]) + 
      Sin[x]^2 Sin[2 y]), 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, -(2/5) (Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] (Cos[y] - Sin[y]) + Sin[x]^2 Sin[2 y]),
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 
   7/5 (Sqrt[2] Cos[y] Sin[2 x] - Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[y] + 
      Sin[x]^2 Sin[2 y])}}
intergral3[x_, y_] := {{6/5 Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[y], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   4/5 Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[y], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   4/5 Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[y], 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, -(14/5) Sqrt[2] Sin[2 x] Sin[y]}}

ωCSt = 2 π 10 (-√2 Sin[2 β] Cos[ωr t + γ] + (Sin[β])^2 Cos[2 ωr t + 2 γ]);

I2z = {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, -(1/2)}}; I2x = {{0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}};
I2y = {{0, -(I/2), 0, 0}, {I/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -(I/2)}, {0, 0, I/2, 0}};
ρ1 = {{0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}};

U1[β_, γ_] := MatrixExp[-I*integral1[β, γ]];

ρ2[β_, γ_] := Dot[U1[β, γ], ρ1, U1[β, γ]\[ConjugateTranspose]]

U2[β_, γ_] := MatrixExp[-I*integral2[β, γ]];

U3 = {{1/Sqrt[2], -(I/Sqrt[2]), 0, 0}, {-(I/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2], -(I/Sqrt[2])}, {0, 0, -(I/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[2]}}

U4[β_, γ_] := MatrixExp[-I*intergral3[β, γ]];

When I use ρ2 to calculate the FreeEvolve2[β, γ] it evaluates fast but when I use ρ7 to evaluate FreeEvolve2[β, γ] it takes huge time (~200X more time) to evaluate.
Has there any way to get rid of this?
Any lead will be really helpful..


Please edit the question and include the complete code, with all relevant definitions (such as U6, U5, r2 ...).

There's a very simple explanation: ρ2 depends on U1 which depends on integral1, which contains numeric (real) numbers. ρ7 on the other hand depends on Ut which depends on U2 which depends on integral2 which contains exact symbolic numbers. When you do FreeEvolve2, you also give exact numbers, which is why the computation is so long when using ρ7. Since the output is nevertheless numeric, you should just give the numeric arguments in the first place (ie. FreeEvolve2[7 Pi/10., 2 Pi/10.]), and then both variants will be equally fast.

Okay, but actually I need to vary both angle: beta & gamma (beta from 0 to Pi with interval of pi/10 and gamma from 0 to 2 Pi in the interval of Pi/5) and finally need to add them all. So I cannot enter the values in the first place. When I vary the angles, it takes enormous time. Following is the code I am using to summing up.
angleMAP =
Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, Range[0, [Pi], [Pi]/10],
Range[0, 2 [Pi], [Pi]/5]], 1]
tot=Total[ParallelMap[FreeEvolve2[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, angleMAP]]

@PPyne wrap your Ranges in N[] to make the set of angles numeric.

@PPyne also note that ParallelMap has some computation overhead, and some Mathematica licences don't allow that many parallel kernels anyway, so I would start with normal Map and get that working first.
